# Swift 4: How to have a sound play over itself when a button is pushed?

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

So my current situation is that whenever I press a button, the sound will restart from the beginning and cut off the already playing sound. What I want is the sound to play over itself when I push the button, so if I push it a second time right after the first time, the second sound would play over the first one and not cut it off. Please let me know if you need clarification on what I need. Here is my code so far:

```
 @IBAction func bull(_ sender: Any) {
    let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Bull", withExtension: "mp3")!

    do
    {
        player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)

        guard let player = player else { return }

        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)

        player.prepareToPlay()
        player.play()
    }

    catch let error
    {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One player can play one sound at a time only. You probably have to do following

Create an array of `players`

```
var arrPlayer: [AVAudioPlayer] = []
```

And then inside your method do the following

```
let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Bull", withExtension: "mp3")!

do
{
    player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)

    arrPlayer.append(player)

    try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient)
    try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)

    arrPlayer.last?.prepareToPlay()
    arrPlayer.last?.play()
}

catch let error
{
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

Comment: I tried this but instead the sound will not play over until it is finished. When I push the button, the sound plays, but when I push it again, I would have to wait until the sound is over for me to play it again.

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question. I have edited my answer. Please check it now.